# c in c++ practices

Tags: c++, c

I normally wouldn't do this, but the project I'm currently working on requires a couple functions that are in a c source file.

```
extern "C" {
    int words(char sentence[]);
    int match(char str[], char sentence[], int n);
}
```

I simply want to know, where is the best place to add these prototypes to the linking functions in c?

Should it be added to the c++ source file (in my case, command.cpp), or the c/c++ header? (command.h)

Comment: Sometimes C source code compiles with a C++ compiler without too much fiddling (I am assuming that the two functions in question are not too long). It is worth a try. Otherwise the answers below using those macros will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least error-prone way is to put the declarations in a shared C & C++ header file, and `#ifdef` the `extern "C" {` to only be used by the C++ compiler (it's a syntax error in C):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  int words(char sentence[]);
  int match(char str[], char sentence[], int n);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I personally also like this variant of pre-#defining a macro for the unscoped `extern` syntax:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define CFUN extern "C"
#else
#define CFUN
#endif

CFUN int words(char sentence[]);
CFUN int match(char str[], char sentence[], int n);
```

This keeps the messy #ifdef stuff localised. You can place it in one of your project-wide header files and use the `CFUN` specifier anywhere. You may want to prefix the name of the `CFUN` macro if it's likely to collide with an existing definition.

Answer (score 3):

The standard idiom is for your header to use the `__cplusplus` macro that C++ defines. So if your C translation unit has the implementation in `file.c`, then you would write the header `file.h` as follows:

```
#ifndef H_FILE
#define H_FILE

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int words(char sentence[]);
int match(char str[], char sentence[], int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif

#endif  // include guard
```

Now you can use the same header both in the C and the C++ translation units.

Comment: The source files do not come with a header file, sadly (nor am I allowed to make one).

Comment: How on earth can you "not be allowed to make one"? What sort of weird programming question does not "allow" you to do certain programming?

Comment: You tell me, these are instructions from my professor. 

Basically, we have to include some functions we've written in C from our previous assignment, into our new assignment. We are not allowed to edit/alter anything but can only include the C file (wordutils.c)  .

Comment: That doesn't preclude you from *creating* a header file and including it in your new C++ file.

Comment: You should absolutely have mentioned in your question that this isn't a real programming problem, but rather a piece artificial homework gymnastics. You really have to do that, or otherwise people will think you're trying to solve an actual problem.

Comment: My apologies. And no, my intent wasn't for you guys to solve my homework, I simply asked for advice where to add the prototype signatures.

Comment: @AJRavindiran: Well, the advice stands as given, but only you can tell whether you'll be able to please your professor.

Answer (score 1):

Well since they are function prototypes declaration same standards as in C++ apply. You should add them to a header file. Unless I totally misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would put them in the cpp file, at the same place where you normally put your forward declarations.
If you use them in more than one cpp file, consider the header. Only then.

Comment: This will work well, but personally I find that if I have to update something in 2 places, I'll probably forget to do so in one of them. Placing the declaration in the header will cause a compile error if you change the function's signature in its definition but not in the header. Keeping them separate won't raise any compile or link errors in this case, you'll just get weird runtime effects. People smarter or less forgetful than me are welcome to ignore this advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, In the header file would be a plus!
But ifdef should used to avoid multi-definition. But in you case, this is not the problem.